Exponentiation of a linear operator
I am trying to go through "Introduction to Functional Analysis" from MITOCW (MATH 18.102) by myself and I am confused by a question in the second problem set.
Let $B$ be a Banach space. Let $\mathfrak{B}(B_1,B_2)$ represent the set of bounded linear operators from $B_1$ to $B_2$ where $B_1$ and $B_2$ are normed vector spaces.
Prove that if $T\in\mathfrak{B}(B,B)$ and $\lVert I-T \rVert$<1 where $I$ is the identity operator, then $T$ is invertible and in fact $\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty(I-T)^n$ converges in $\mathfrak{B}(B,B)$ to $T^{-1}$
I am confused by what $(I-T)^n$ is supposed to mean , in the context of bounded linear operators of Banach Spaces , or more generally vector spaces
Is $(I-T)^n$ a typo or did I miss something? If it is a typo, what is it supposed to say?
I am not aware of any standard way of multiplication or exponentiation on vector spaces or specifically Banach spaces. I could not find any when I searched it up either. The only example I could think of was maybe the wedge product provides a  way of defining multiplication, but does not define a good way to exponentiate since the wedge product of anything with itself is 0. Specifically in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the only product I could think of was the cross product, and there the same problem as with the wedge product occurs.
If $(I-T)^n$ is a typo, I could not think of any series in particular that approaches the inverse defined similarly.

$T^{2}=T\circ T, T^{3}=T\circ T^{2}$ etc.

You should have $I$ in "$||I-T|| < 1$" as well.  $I(x) = x$ and it might be useful to think of how this notation is used when computing eigenvalues of linear maps (waaaaay back in linear algebra).  $(I-T)(x) = I(x) - T(x) = x - T(x)$.  $(I-T)^2(x) = (I-T)((I-T)(x)) = (I-T)(x - T(x)) = (x - T(x)) - T(x - T(x))$.

Thank you for pointing that out, typo on my end. Fixed now

If $f$ is a function from a space $B$ to itself, then $f^i$ means you apply $f$ i times:
$$f^3: B\overset{f}{\rightarrow}B\overset{f}{\rightarrow}B\overset{f}{\rightarrow}B$$
$$f^5: B\overset{f}{\rightarrow}B\overset{f}{\rightarrow}B\overset{f}{\rightarrow}B\overset{f}{\rightarrow}B\overset{f}{\rightarrow}B$$
Invertible endomorphisms are called automorphisms and under functional compositoin $f\cdot g= f\circ g$ form a group called $\text{Aut}(B)$.
Since $I, T$ are both endomorophisms (they go from $B$ to $B$), $I-T$ is also well defined as an endomorphism. Thus we can defined $(I-T)^n$ as applying $I-T$ $n$-times to some input $x\in B$.

(1) There might be a typo , though not where you think it is.
The $1$ should ideally by $I$ , which will make "where $I$ is the identity operator" make sense , adding to what Eric Towers commented.
That Authors might have mentioned earlier that $1 \equiv I$ (which is just convenient shorthand) , in which case there is no typo at all.
[[ UPDATE : this was a typo by the OP , which has been rectified ]]
(2) Speaking Intuitively/loosely , we can take the Summation via Geometric Series / Progression to get :
$\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}(I-T)^n=(I-T)^0+(I-T)^1+(I-T)^2+(I-T)^3+\cdots$
[[ UPDATE : here $(I-T)^2$ is just shorthand for $(I-T)(I-T)$ which indicates applying the Operator $(I-T)$ twice. Likewise for higher $n$ , where $(I-T)^n$ indicates applying the Operator $(I-T)$ $n$ times ]]
$\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}(I-T)^n=I+(I-T)+(I-T)^2+(I-T)^3+\cdots$
This is Converging , due to the $||\cdot||$ Criteria given.
$\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}(I-T)^n=I/(I-[I-T])$ which is $I/T$
Now , $I/T \equiv T^{-1}$ (intuitive shorthand) will give us :
$\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}(I-T)^n=T^{-1}$ when $T$ is Invertible.
